# Slow SQL Query on large database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL query to find data that does not exist in another table and due to the replace sequences its taking over 35 minutes to complete?

```
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(4) = 'UUID'
DECLARE @p1 NVarChar(1) = ''
DECLARE @p2 NVarChar(1) = 'p'
DECLARE @p3 NVarChar(1) = ''
DECLARE @p4 NVarChar(4) = 'UUID'
DECLARE @p5 NVarChar(1) = ''
DECLARE @p6 NVarChar(1) = 'p'
DECLARE @p7 NVarChar(1) = ''

SELECT 
    u.ProductUUID, u.id, c.id, c.MappingUUID
FROM 
    dbo.Product_Data u
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.Mapping_Data c ON REPLACE(REPLACE(c.MappingUUID, @p0, @p1), @p2, @p3) = REPLACE(REPLACE(u.ProductUUID, @p4, @p5), @p6, @p7)
WHERE 
    c.GN_Paid IS NULL
```

The 2x `replace` statements are because of 2 different prefixes that can occur between the 2 tables:

Table 1:

```
UUID0000000000165019
```

Table 2:

```
i00165019
```

Although they end with the same id, I was looking at replacing the beginning and returning the results but it seems this is inefficient so wonder if any of you gurus have dealt with this and use a different method?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: `REPLACE()` in the `ON` clause is pretty much going to kill performance.  I would suggest that you fix the `JOIN` keys and then try again.

Comment: I can agree with @GordonLinoff. You are forcing the engine to evaluate all records of table `u` against all records of table `c`, That's a lot of operations

Comment: Seems like a `UNION` would solve this issue.

Comment: thanks guys let me look into that one and try to refactor

Answer (score 0):

OK Thanks for those who responded as this was useful in pointing out the slow areas.

I managed to move this across to linq with linqpad and refactor which now returns the correct results within 15 seconds.